Error when setting seed with imputeMFA function
I am trying to run the imputeMFA function from the missMDA package and I want to check how stable the solution is compared to other imputation methods, so I cannot use the default where seed = NULL. I need to introduce a variety of seeds to get a variety of solutions. But the code is crashing whenever I set a seed. Any idea what can I do?
The code I have:
> library(missRows)
> library(FactoMineR)
> library(ade4)
> library(missMDA)

# ARRANGING THE DATA ########################################
> data(NCI60)
> tableList <- NCI60$dataTables[1:2]
> cell.line <- NCI60$dataTables$cell.line
> transposed_list <- lapply(tableList, function(df) t(df))
> merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "row.names", all = TRUE), transposed_list)
> num_columns <- sapply(transposed_list, function(df) ncol(df))


# IMPUTING WITHOUT SEED ####################################
> imp <- imputeMFA(merged_df, group = num_columns, ncp = 7) # Works without any issue
# IMPUTING WITH SEED #######################################
> impSeed <- imputeMFA(merged_df, group = c(300,162), ncp = 7, seed = 1234)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 17983, 60
> impSeed <- imputeMFA(merged_df, group = c(300,162), ncp = 7, seed = 1)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 17983, 60
> impSeed <- imputeMFA(merged_df, group = c(300,162), ncp = 7, seed = 4946)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 17983, 60

I tried in two environments: my personal CPU and Google Colab.
Google Colab is sending a little bit more info:
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 17983, 60
Traceback:

1. imputeMFA(merged_df, group = c(300, 162), ncp = 7, seed = 1234)

2. impute(X, group = group, ncp = ncp, type = type, method = method, 
 .     threshold = threshold, seed = seed, maxiter = maxiter, row.w = row.w, 
 .     ind.sup = ind.sup, num.group.sup = num.group.sup, coeff.ridge = coeff.ridge)

3. cbind.data.frame(Xhat, aux.base/ponderation[g])

4. data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)

5. stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
 .     paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)

Google Colab's Session Info:
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Etc/UTC
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rcellminer_2.26.0           rcellminerData_2.26.0      
 [3] omicade4_1.44.0             pacman_0.5.1               
 [5] missRows_1.24.0             MultiAssayExperiment_1.30.1
 [7] SummarizedExperiment_1.34.0 Biobase_2.64.0             
 [9] GenomicRanges_1.56.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.40.0        
[11] IRanges_2.38.0              S4Vectors_0.42.0           
[13] BiocGenerics_0.50.0         MatrixGenerics_1.16.0      
[15] matrixStats_1.3.0           missMDA_1.19               
[17] mice_3.16.0                 RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
[19] ggplot2_3.4.4               gtools_3.9.5               
[21] dplyr_1.1.4                 plyr_1.8.9                 
[23] ade4_1.7-22                 FactoMineR_2.11            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-7            rlang_1.1.3             magrittr_2.0.3         
 [4] compiler_4.4.0          vctrs_0.6.5             stringr_1.5.1          
 [7] pkgconfig_2.0.3         shape_1.4.6.1           crayon_1.5.2           
[10] fastmap_1.1.1           backports_1.4.1         XVector_0.44.0         
[13] labeling_0.4.3          caTools_1.18.2          utf8_1.2.4             
[16] UCSC.utils_1.0.0        nloptr_2.0.3            purrr_1.0.2            
[19] glmnet_4.1-8            jomo_2.7-6              made4_1.78.0           
[22] zlibbioc_1.50.0         jsonlite_1.8.8          flashClust_1.01-2      
[25] DelayedArray_0.30.1     uuid_1.2-0              pan_1.9                
[28] broom_1.0.5             parallel_4.4.0          cluster_2.1.6          
[31] R6_2.5.1                stringi_1.8.3           boot_1.3-30            
[34] rpart_4.1.23            estimability_1.5        Rcpp_1.0.12            
[37] IRkernel_1.3.2          iterators_1.0.14        base64enc_0.1-3        
[40] Matrix_1.6-5            splines_4.4.0           nnet_7.3-19            
[43] tidyselect_1.2.0        abind_1.4-5             gplots_3.1.3.1         
[46] doParallel_1.0.17       codetools_0.2-19        lattice_0.22-5         
[49] tibble_3.2.1            withr_3.0.0             evaluate_0.23          
[52] survival_3.5-8          pillar_1.9.0            BiocManager_1.30.23    
[55] KernSmooth_2.23-22      DT_0.33                 foreach_1.5.2          
[58] generics_0.1.3          IRdisplay_1.1           munsell_0.5.0          
[61] scales_1.3.0            minqa_1.2.6             leaps_3.1              
[64] glue_1.7.0              emmeans_1.10.1          scatterplot3d_0.3-44   
[67] tools_4.4.0             lme4_1.1-35.3           pbdZMQ_0.3-11          
[70] mvtnorm_1.2-4           grid_4.4.0              tidyr_1.3.1            
[73] colorspace_2.1-0        nlme_3.1-163            GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.12
[76] repr_1.1.7              cli_3.6.2               fansi_1.0.6            
[79] S4Arrays_1.4.0          gtable_0.3.4            digest_0.6.34          
[82] SparseArray_1.4.3       ggrepel_0.9.5           farver_2.1.1           
[85] htmlwidgets_1.6.4       htmltools_0.5.7         lifecycle_1.0.4        
[88] httr_1.4.7              multcompView_0.1-10     mitml_0.4-5            
[91] MASS_7.3-60.0.1        

My CPU's
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Etc/GMT+6
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] VIM_6.2.2                   colorspace_2.1-0            missRows_1.22.0            
 [4] MultiAssayExperiment_1.28.0 SummarizedExperiment_1.32.0 GenomicRanges_1.54.1       
 [7] GenomeInfoDb_1.38.8         IRanges_2.36.0              S4Vectors_0.40.2           
[10] MatrixGenerics_1.14.0       matrixStats_1.1.0           sp_2.1-4                   
[13] missMDA_1.19                mice_3.16.0                 RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
[16] rcellminer_2.24.0           rcellminerData_2.24.0       Biobase_2.62.0             
[19] BiocGenerics_0.48.1         omicade4_1.42.0             ggplot2_3.5.1              
[22] gtools_3.9.5                dplyr_1.1.2                 plyr_1.8.8                 
[25] ade4_1.7-22                 FactoMineR_2.11             pacman_0.5.1               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] vcd_1.4-12              rstudioapi_0.16.0       shape_1.4.6.1          
  [4] magrittr_2.0.3          TH.data_1.1-2           estimability_1.5       
  [7] jomo_2.7-6              farver_2.1.1            nloptr_2.0.3           
 [10] rmarkdown_2.26          zlibbioc_1.48.2         vctrs_0.6.3            
 [13] minqa_1.2.6             RCurl_1.98-1.14         htmltools_0.5.8.1      
 [16] S4Arrays_1.2.1          broom_1.0.5             SparseArray_1.2.4      
 [19] mitml_0.4-5             KernSmooth_2.23-22      htmlwidgets_1.6.4      
 [22] sandwich_3.1-0          emmeans_1.10.1          zoo_1.8-12             
 [25] lifecycle_1.0.4         iterators_1.0.14        pkgconfig_2.0.3        
 [28] Matrix_1.6-5            R6_2.5.1                fastmap_1.1.1          
 [31] GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.11 digest_0.6.32           pkgload_1.3.4          
 [34] labeling_0.4.3          fansi_1.0.4             abind_1.4-5            
 [37] compiler_4.3.3          proxy_0.4-27            withr_3.0.0            
 [40] doParallel_1.0.17       backports_1.4.1         carData_3.0-5          
 [43] gplots_3.1.3.1          pan_1.9                 MASS_7.3-60.0.1        
 [46] DelayedArray_0.28.0     scatterplot3d_0.3-44    caTools_1.18.2         
 [49] flashClust_1.01-2       tools_4.3.3             lmtest_0.9-40          
 [52] ranger_0.16.0           nnet_7.3-19             glue_1.6.2             
 [55] nlme_3.1-164            cluster_2.1.6           generics_0.1.3         
 [58] gtable_0.3.5            class_7.3-22            tidyr_1.3.0            
 [61] data.table_1.15.4       car_3.1-2               utf8_1.2.3             
 [64] XVector_0.42.0          ggrepel_0.9.3           foreach_1.5.2          
 [67] pillar_1.9.0            stringr_1.5.1           robustbase_0.99-2      
 [70] splines_4.3.3           lattice_0.22-5          survival_3.5-8         
 [73] tidyselect_1.2.1        made4_1.76.0            knitr_1.46             
 [76] xfun_0.43               DEoptimR_1.1-3          DT_0.33                
 [79] stringi_1.7.12          yaml_2.3.7              boot_1.3-29            
 [82] evaluate_0.23           codetools_0.2-19        laeken_0.5.3           
 [85] tibble_3.2.1            BiocManager_1.30.23     multcompView_0.1-10    
 [88] cli_3.6.1               rpart_4.1.23            xtable_1.8-4           
 [91] munsell_0.5.1           Rcpp_1.0.10             coda_0.19-4.1          
 [94] parallel_4.3.3          leaps_3.1               bitops_1.0-7           
 [97] lme4_1.1-35.3           glmnet_4.1-8            mvtnorm_1.2-2          
[100] scales_1.3.0            e1071_1.7-14            purrr_1.0.1            
[103] crayon_1.5.2            rlang_1.1.1             multcomp_1.4-25 


Since I am a noobie and not allowed to answer my own questions, I will share the solution I found here:
In the function, the line Xhat[missing,] <- rnorm(length(missing)) is being understood by R as an order to create more rows in the Xhat dataframe instead of filling the empty cells. The solution is removing the comma and transforming Xhat into a matrix beforehand. I already sent the developer a note but this could be implemented by anyone as their own function.
